# DB2 access specific row, in an non Unique table, for update / delete operations

Tags: db2, crud, ibm-midrange, db2-400

Can I do row-specific update / delete operations in a DB2 table Via SQL, in a NON QUNIQUE Primary Key Context?

The Table is a PHYSICAL FILE on the NATIVE SYSTEM of the AS/400.
It was, like many other Files, created without the unique definition, which leads DB2 to the conclusion, that The Table, or PF has no qunique Key.

And that's my problem. I can't override the structure of the table to insert a unique ID ROW, because, I would have to recompile ALL my correlating Programs on the AS/400, which is a serious issue, much things would not work anymore, "perhaps". Of course, I can do that refactoring for one table, but our system has thousands of those native  FILES, some well done with Unique Key, some without Unique definition...

Well, I work most of the time with db2 and sql on that old files. And all files which have a UNIQUE Key are no problem for me to do those important update / delete operations.

Is there some way to get an additional column to every select with a very unique row id, respective row number. And in addition, what is much more important, how can I update this RowNumber.

I did some research and meanwhile I assume, that there is no chance to do exact alterations or deletes, when there is no unique key present. What I would wish would be some additional ID-ROW which is always been sent with the table, which I can Refer to when I do my update / delete operations. Perhaps my thinking here has an fallacy as non Unique Key Tables are purposed to be edited in other ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [RRN](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscarrn.htm) function.

```
SELECT RRN(EMPLOYEE), LASTNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE ...;

UPDATE EMPLOYEE
SET ...
WHERE RRN(EMPLOYEE) = ...;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's it! Exactly, i'm a bit embarrased that i didn't find it myself, but i searched my ass up. Unfortunately the IBM Help isn't structured that well in my opinion, or i was just too dumb :]. Thanks again!

Comment: @dc-deal BE CAREFUL! RRN can change if a RGZPFM is done, so use it only for immediate use